# firebase deeplink URL not opening in windows browser

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We are generating firebase deeplink URL and when we copy that link and paste in browser its not opening just blank screen will be visible. Can you please help what might be the cause?

Tried multiple settings in firebase but still it doesn't work. Same works well in Linux box.

URL format will be like this: https://m.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/CgC4